# Problem while running "yarn run dev" and error with exit code 1

Tags: next.js, yarnpkg

I have windows 11 and I have installed latest LTS version of node.js. I was trying to create next app. I installed yarn and created next app by "yarn create next-app" command. I named the folder "Panda" and inside that folder when I am running "yarn run dev", I am getting an error saying "using wasm build of next-swc command failed with exit code 1".

I am attaching the screenshot of the error as well.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sAh9.png)

I tried creating a ".babelrc" and wrote

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"]
}
```

as instructed on [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/failed-loading-swc) page.

I tried reinstalling node.js and somehow previously x86 architecture was installed but now I have x64. And now while running "yarn run dev" I am getting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu3Bc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reinstalled node.js and then reinstalled yarn by running "yarn upgrade next", as I saw later that somehow x84 structure of node.js was installed.